# Find vertices without any predecessor/ingoing edges in igraph R

Tags: r, igraph, graph-databases

How can I get the vertices that don't have any predecessor in the graph. For example, this is the graph data:

```
lfs = data.table( from = c('x', 'x', 'y'), to = c('y', 'p', 'z'))
lfs
#  from to
#:    x  y
#:    x  p
#:    y  z
g = graph_from_data_frame(lfs)
g
# IGRAPH DN-- 4 3 --
# + attr: name (v/c)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] x->y x->p y->z
```

In this graph `x` does not have any predecessor. Is there any query function to get such vertices easily?

Comment: `as_edgelist(g)` will give you a `matrix` in which the first column is the "parent" node and the second is the "child". Nodes with no parents are the ones that don't appear in the second column. You can try `setdiff(V(g)$name,as_edgelist(g)[,2])`.

Comment: Have a look at `?ego` ; which you can use to find ancestors (and descendants)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `degree` to find the edges going into a node

```
library(igraph)
lfs <- data.frame( from = c('x', 'x', 'y'), to = c('y', 'p', 'z'))    
g <- graph_from_data_frame(lfs)

# find the edges in to a node
degree(g, mode="in")
#x y p z 
#0 1 1 1

# You can then subset to get the node names
V(g)$name[!degree(g, mode="in")]
# "x"
```